# lodash get items from array that does not match array of values

Tags: javascript, lodash

To get items from array that match array of values I use this:

```
var result =_(response).keyBy('id').at(arrayOfIDs).value();
```

How can I do the opposite? Get items that does not match array of values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is easily done with vanilla JS.

```
var nonMatchingItems = response.filter(function (item) {
    return arrayOfIDs.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
});
```

The same approach is possible with [lodash's `_.filter()`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter), if you positively must use lodash.

ES6 version of the above:

```
var nonMatchingItems = response.filter(item => arrayOfIDs.indexOf(item.id) === -1);

// or, shorter
var nonMatchingItems = response.filter(item => !arrayOfIDs.includes(item.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lodash, just use plain javascript; it's easier to read as well...

```
function getId (val) {
    return val.id;
}

function notMatchId (val) {
    return arrayOfIDs.indexOf(val) === -1;
}

var result = response.map(getId).filter(notMatchId);
```

Comment: Not really correct, this returns a list of IDs, the OP wants the associated items.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the pullAll (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pullAll) function :

```
const result = _.pullAll([...response], arrayOfIDs);
```